# How to give an automated response back when receiving a specific message from the client (Java, sockets)

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, server, client

I basically was trying to give a response back from my server if my client sends me the message "Hello mr server". However it doesn't.

Here is my code :

```
public class Server {

    public static final int PORT = 6666;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Server().runServer();
    }

    public void runServer() throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        System.out.println("Server up and ready for connections.....");
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); //for fetching data
            String str = br.readLine(); //for fetching data

            System.out.println("Client Data:" + str + '\n');


            String dataSendingToClient = "gg";
            OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()); //for sending data
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(os); //for sending data
            out.println(dataSendingToClient);
            os.flush();



            if (br.equals("hey mr server")){
                OutputStreamWriter os2 = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()); //for sending data
                PrintWriter out2 = new PrintWriter(os); //for sending data
                out2.println("hey mr client");
                os.flush();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please try and expand on what you've tried and what you are getting instead (e.g. error output).

Answer (score 0):

You are using `br.equals("hey mr server")` which will always return false, since `br` is not a String, but a BufferedReader

Instead you should use your already defined `str` variable `str.equals("hey mr server")`

---

Also note that with your current code, your server will only read one message from the client before moving on to the next connection

If you want your server to read more messages from a single client, you will need to loop until the client sends a disconnect message/the socket closes

```
while(true)
{
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    BufferedReader br = [...];
    PrintWriter out = [...];

    for(String message = br.readLine(); message != null; message = br.readLine())
    {
        //do stuff
        //message is each line from the client
    }
}
```

If you have multiple clients trying to connect, you will need to multithread the connections

I would recommend a class to enclose the connection details and use Stacks to poll if the client sent data

```
public static void main(String[] args) //or whatever other method you're running in
{
    List<Connection> clients = new ArrayList<Connection>(); //some data structure to hold the clients

    //start accepting connections
    new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                while(true)
                    Connection client = new Connection(serverSocket.accept());
            }
        }).start();

    //do something with the clients, read/write/whatever
}

private class Connection extends Runnable
{
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private Queue<String> messages;

    public Connection(Socket s)
    {
        reader = [...];
        writer = [...];
        messages = new LinkedList<String>();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        //just keep reading
        while(true)
            messages.add(reader.readLine();
    }

    public String read()
    {
        messages.poll();
    }

    public void write(String msg)
    {
        writer.write(msg);
        writer.flush();
    }
}
```

Note: take that as rough pseudocode

Comment: Thank you for your input, if I may ask how would I get it to read more?